# Changing select option text color property within manually insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm trying to change text color inside an `option` with the `style.color` property while inserting in to a `select` without success.
its working on browser but not on mobile device

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var x = document.getElementById("selectCode");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = i;
    option.text = i;
    option.style.color = 'darkblue';
    x.add(option);  
}
```

Is `style.color = 'colorname'` property approachable with javascript on mobile device, if not what is the approachable way?

Here is my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LL6ued7f/)

Comment: im using it within phonegap application

Comment: Why are you using a `background-color` CSS property when you want to change text color? This should be `color` if you want to change text colors manually. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/YBr8S/248/

Comment: update jsfiddle, mistake

Comment: @fatalica your js working properly. You can see `  color: rgb(0, 0, 139);` property in developer tool of every `option`. See this https://jsfiddle.net/LL6ued7f/1/ with `red` color.

Comment: check my post , updated it.

Comment: @fatalica once again: code in question has nothing to do with jQuery, so this tag is not relevant one here. About mobile devices: are you sure that problem is in them, not in other code?

Comment: in fact im using jquery also so i think it relevant , and yes as i mentioned same code working on browser but not on emulator or device.

Comment: @Manwal why do you think that DOM Element's `.style.color` doesn't work on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the color of the `option` when they are added. You have to add the options first to change the style of the `option`. Simply change `option.style.color` to `x.style.color` and put it at the bottom of the for-loop

**Javascript**

```
for(var i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    var x = document.getElementById("selectCode");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = i;
    option.text = i;
    x.add(option);
    x.style.color = "#0000FF";  
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LL6ued7f/3/

Comment: tried, dosn't seems to work on mobile device at my phonegap application